# Lua requires a } to close a { that is already closed

Tags: lua, love2d

This issue actually only appears if I a single more line to the "player" class.

Code:

```
function love.load()
player = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    dky = character
    y_velocity = 0,
    jump_time = 1,
    jump_time_max = 1,
    character = love.graphics.newImage("gfx/character.png")
}
gravity = 400
jump_height = 300
winW, winH = love.graphics.getWidth(), love.graphics.getHeight()
```

end

Comment: Could you please post the working code and the change that you made?

Comment: You're also missing an `end` for the function, and the body of the function is not properly indented.

Comment: Add comma after `dky = character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to add a comma after

> `character = love.graphics.newImage("gfx/character.png")`

when you added another line to `player`.

The code you give already has this problem: a missing comma after `dky = character`.